# Return only some keys from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to display the array but only with name and age

```js
 const users = [{name: 'john', age: 20, instrument: 'guitar'}, {name: 'mary', age: 20, instrument: 'piano'}];
let userList =  users.map(users => {name: users.name, users.instrument })
console.log(userList);
```

didn't work. I'm missing a return somewhere right?

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap the object statement in each iteration with `()`.

Also, I prefer using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const users = [{name: 'john', age: 20, instrument: 'guitar'}, {name: 'mary', age: 20, instrument: 'piano'}];
var new_users = users.map(({name,instrument})  => ({name, instrument}));
console.log(new_users);
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to wrap object inside `()`

```js
const users = [{name: 'john', age: 20, instrument: 'guitar'}, {name: 'mary', age: 20, instrument: 'piano'}];
var result = users.map(user => ({ name: user.name, instrument: user.instrument }));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You forgot an `=` when setting `users`.
2. Inside the map function, you called the run-through-object `users` but use `user`.
3. You forgot an `'` after `'guitar`
4. You didn't set the key for the instrument value in the mapping function
5. You need to add brackets `()` around the object in the mapping function as it will be treated as arrow function if forgotten

In the end it should look like this:

```js
const users = [{name: 'john', age: 20, instrument: 'guitar'}, {name: 'mary', age: 20, instrument: 'piano'}];

const mapped = users.map(user => ({name: user.name, instrument: user.instrument}));

console.log(mapped);
```